# RewriteRule gives me unwanted $_GET param

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I need `video/5` to be `video.php?id=5`

```
RewriteRule ^video$ video.php [L]
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/?$ video.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

esentially - the above code works - but here is a problem:

`video/` - without `id` - gives me an empty string as `$_GET['id']`

so if I write:

`if(isset($_GET['id']))...` - the result is `true` and the value is `""`

how to avoid this ?

I want just `video/` - without any $_GET variable - except it is set explicitly - for example - `video/5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Internal rewrite to video.php without $1 in it.
RewriteRule ^video/?$ video.php [NC,L]

##Rules for internal rewrite with passing id query string to it.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/?$ video.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: tried. `video` - without slash - there is no id set. But `video/` - produces id

Comment: @provance, ok I have edited it now, please try my edited rules once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: the same result. `video` - without slash - there is no id set. But `video/` - produces id

Comment: @provance, ok sure, I think I got it this time, I have edited the rules, kindly do check edited rules once and let me know if this help you. Cheers.

Comment: it works. What is the holy secret pls? You just replaced the order of lines ?

Comment: @provance, Your welcome, happy to help :) There is nothing like secret. Its simple I have changed the order of rules and added condition before rule where we need `id` that if its comes from browser then only execute it, hence we are Good with both the rules :) cheers and happy learning.